# PHP Time Arithmetic

Tags: php, datetime

I have two times in my database:

```
$time1 = "02:00:03";
$time2 = "04:00:04";
```

and I want to make add them `$time1 + $time2` what is the best way to do that?

I have no problem with the diference cause I can do something like this:

```
$end = new DateTime($this->hora_final);
$start = new DateTime($this->hora_inicio);
$diff = $end->diff($start);

$diff->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

and it works perfectly... but i can't seem to find a way to add them... any ideas?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DateTime::add()`](http://php.net/datetime.add). It really doesn't make much sense to add two dates, thus you cannot treat `$time2` as `DateTime`, to add it to `time1`. Usually you would say something like `01.04. + 2 days`, but not `01.04. + 02.00`. The method accepts an object of type [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/class.dateinterval). To create it I suggest to use something like

```
list($hour, $min, $second) = explode(':', $time2);
$interval = new DateInterval("PT{$hour}H{$min}M{$second}S");
```

Now you should be able to add the interval to the date

```
$x = new DateTime($time1);
$y = $x->add($interval);
```

(untested)

Comment: i don't need the date part.. i just need to add to times with this format H:m:s

Comment: ehm ... thats what I described :? Its just about: `date + interval = date` and (according your "diff" example) `date - date = interval` (Matematical: `x - y = z <=> x = z + y` ;))

Comment: yep i haven't seen the modification when i posted the comment :) worked like a charm with a minor modification to: 
list($hour, $min, $second) = $time2;
for list($hour, $min, $second) = explode(":", $time2);