# Laravel 5 Time Difference

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have an application which on sign in records in time and on sign out records out time.

My table has IN_TIME & OUT_TIME

**Example of data within those columns:**

IN_TIME = 16:06:46

OUT_TIME = 16:08:07

I have a controller which to my blade template file is showing all attedances for a given person, what I want to do is show the time difference between the two.

See below my current code which currently shows 0

```
**Time onsite:** {{ date('G:i', strtotime($attrec->out_time)) - date('G:i', strtotime($attrec->in_time)) }}
```

Is there a reason why I can't get the right figure?

Comment: Look into Carbon, which is already built into laravel: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff

Comment: Can I use carbon in my view though?

Comment: @Wolrab Sure you can.

Comment: Sure. You can use it anywhere in laravel.

Comment: If you remove the logic, and just do `{{ strtotime($attrec->out_time) }}` what is produced?

Comment: @camelCase 1452010087 at the moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're converting the timestamps to formatted strings and trying to compute the difference between the strings. Instead you should compute the difference between the results of each `datetotime` (which return UNIX timestamps that are essentially seconds) and then format that result:

```
{{ date('G:i', strtotime($attrec->out_time) - strtotime($attrec->in_time)) }}
```

You can also use [`Carbon`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference) by doing the following:

```
{{ (new Carbon($attrec->out_time))->diff(new Carbon($attrec->in_time))->format('%h:%I') }}
```

This uses method [`diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) inherited from `DateTime`, which returns a `DateInterval` instance. The formatting characters for [`DateInterval::format`](http://php.net/manual/ro/dateinterval.format.php) are different from the ones used by [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). That's why the formatting string is `%h:%I`, which is the equivalent of `G:i`.

The above code will output:

```
0:01
```

Because you chose to format the hour without leading zeros, and the difference between the two timestamps is one minute (and some spare seconds that are not shown because they are not included in the formatting string).

Comment: Thanks @bogdan, new to CARBON! I've tried you're method but I get syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Probably a trailing `)` at the end, try removing

Comment: @camelCase is right, my bad :). There was a trailing `)` there. @Wolrab I've also updated my answer with an additional solution using `date` and `strtotime` as an alternative to Carbon.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but it's probably that arithmetic operations are undefined on the output of `date`. I'm not familiar with PHP but bash for instance will apply a numeric value of "0" to anything that's not a number that you try to add. So if you did

```
"hello" + 5
```

you'd get 5. In this case you'd have two objects evaluated as 0 giving `0 + 0 = 0`

There's a question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609429/php-time-arithmetic) that addresses time arithmetic in PHP. Hopefully that will set you on the best way to achieve what you want!

Answer (score 0):

Inside Controller you can write like below

```
$today_check_in = Carbon::parse($attrec->in_time);
$check_out = Carbon::parse($attrec->out_time);
$duration = $today_check_in->diff($check_out)->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

OUTPUT will be like this .
`00:02:39`