# How can I compare now and datetime ? Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

My code is like this :

```
foreach ($orders as $order) 
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
    $now_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $delivered_at = $order->delivered_at->toDateTimeString();
    $delivered_after_1d = strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($delivered_at));
    $delivered_after_1d = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $delivered_after_1d);
    if($now_at > $delivered_after_1d) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

It works

But I want change it using laravel. For example use `Carbon::now()`. But I'm confused

Is there anyone who can help me?

Note :

delivered_at : data type = datetime

Comment: Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616429/laravel-5-time-difference

Answer (score 1):

You can write this. Hopefully this will solve your problem

```
foreach ($orders as $order) 
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
    $now_at = Carbon::now();
    $delivered_at = $order->delivered_at->toDateTimeString();
    $delivered_after_1d = $delivered_at->addDays(1);
    if($now_at > $delivered_after_1d) 
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

Also write `use Carbon\Carbon;` at the beginning of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the field name in the model under the `protected $dates = ['array','of','fields']`
 and they would be casted to carbon instances